# Cannot install GWT plugin to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

My task is to create a GWT project. I want to replicate what is done in 
[this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/tutorials/stockwatcher) tutorial.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler 4.3, the newest version of the software and for installing GWT plugin I go to **Help > Install New Software** and I paste there this link: http: //dl. google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3 (which I believe is the good one because it is for the 4.3 version)

I check all the stuff only without the Android related one, like in [this](https://imgur.com/quNYsVw) picture, click next,next and wait for installation.

Somewhere in the middle of the installation it pops up a message saying:

> Warning! You are installing software that contains unsigned content.
>   The authenticity or validity of this software cannot be established.
>   Do you want to continue with the installation?

I click OK, even if I think here is the whole stuff goes wrong.

After I click OK, the installation goes very fast, maybe because it skips some files. After that I must restart my Eclipse and I start following the tutorial with the StockWatcher.

But when I go to **Window > Preferences > WindowBuilder** I have only CodeParsing there, there is no **GWT**, I checked **Window > Preferences > Google** where I have **Web Toolkit > Designer** but here is only stuff about Layout, Code Style and Event Handler.

In **Preferences > Google > AppEngine** I have the file from their website and **Preferences > Google > Web Toolkit** their file too.

When I try to create a new project, there is **no GWT Java Project**...

Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems plugin installed in eclipse. there is no such GWT java project option. did you find `web application project` option while creating new  project?

Comment: Yes, I can select that kind of project, it creates it but it is full of errors like **Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater**, I'm using 1.8

Comment: It suggests me to change some stuff back to 1.5, I do that, the errors are gone, but when I try to run it, it fails and gives me this error: `Jan 13, 2015 5:12:35 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.AppEngineDevAgent premain
SEVERE: Unable to load the App Engine dev agent. Security restrictions will not be completely emulated.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception during cast.
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl.cast(ClearCast.java:385)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast.staticCast(ClearCast.java:252)
` ...

Comment: Do right click ->Properties->Java Compiler->Enable Project Specific Setting-> Set 1.5 or Greater jdk option. and as your second post: app engine should disable if you don't want in project, while creating pure GWT project.

Comment: I've done what you've told me and it goes the same as previous, no errors in classes, but crashes when run. It says that port 8888 is busy, maybe used by another thing, but I went to Task Manager and no app is using that port..

Comment: Do you know any other way/tutorial to install GWT plugin in Eclipse that works? That can make me capable after installing it, of creating that StockWatcher tutorial.

Comment: port 8888 is busy. this means eclipse is already running your program. and you are trying to execute same. first stop it and then do start again. refer https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0

Comment: it still doesn't works..

Comment: this is what pops up during installation of the plugin: http://i.imgur.com/LgtI8sN.png

Comment: That's "normal" (as in, it shouldn't be, but it is). Just click OK. It even says so [on the official website](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4).

Comment: But before that message pops up, the installation is going slow and after I click OK, it goes very fast, like it skipped something. And in the tutorial at **Window > Preferences > WindowBuilder** there is an option called **GWT** which isn't in my case. And I cannot continue making the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT is no longer featured in Eclipse