# Cannot create a GWT Web Application Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I had some problems after installing GWT plugin in Eclipse, I've talked about them **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914291/cannot-install-gwt-plugin-to-eclipse)** but I haven't find useful help for my problem.

So there is another thing here. I have the option to create a **Web Application Project**. So I create one, give it the name "Demo", I check Use Google Web Toolkit, Use Default SDK 2.6.0, Use Google App Engine, Default 1.9.17 and after that I click Finish.

It generates me a project with 4 packages, 2 of them, Client and Server have that red circle with an x inside them which indicates that there are errors. Each class have them too.

When I click on them, it says:

> Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5
>   or greater

and it indicates me to change it. I aprove it, the red dots dissapear after that from classes and packages but one remains on the project directory.

When I run the project it shows this in console:

```
    Jan 19, 2015 2:09:23 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.AppEngineDevAgent premain
SEVERE: Unable to load the App Engine dev agent. Security restrictions will not be completely emulated.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception during cast.
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl.cast(ClearCast.java:385)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast.staticCast(ClearCast.java:252)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast.staticCast(ClearCast.java:263)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.AppEngineDevAgent.premain(AppEngineDevAgent.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl can not access a member of class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.$Proxy0 with modifiers "public"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl.cast(ClearCast.java:383)
    ... 9 more
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get this error when I run using Java 1.8 and when I changed it to 1.7, this solved the problem.

Edit: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. Checked jre7 to make it default.

Comment: I've done what you have said. First time, when I've used Java 8, when running a sample project called 'Testing' and clicking on the link generated below it will show this: http://i.imgur.com/XnLmL8w.png but it didn't let me to install that plugin.                                                           Second time, after changing to Java 7, after clicking the link it show this on browser: http://i.imgur.com/tybn8nZ.png